# Source for anecdote with Moses Montefiore and Charity

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity, story-identification

I have heard an anecdote told of Moses Montefiore explaining that his 'worth' was only what he gave to charity. This story is quoted in many places (ex. [1](http://www.oocities.org/shishusansar/stories/greatpeople/10-montefiore.htm), [2](http://tmt.urj.net/archives/1torahstudy/112309.htm), [3](https://www.facebook.com/rabbidovgreenberg/posts/1714731698772449:0)) to underscore the value of charity. I would like to know the source of the story. In [one version](https://books.google.com/books?id=CVhKAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&lpg=PT73&dq=sir%20moses%20what%20are%20you%20worth?%20queens&source=bl&ots=1dkADAmr6C&sig=EcRZw9GeKjZxgLlE_aiSpD9zf0s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt4Ja-vrzVAhWK8oMKHcl9CMkQ6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=sir%20moses%20what%20are%20you%20worth%3F%20queens&f=false) I saw that the London Times published it along with other anecdotes to mark Montefiore's 100th birthday, but I have not been able to corroborate that.

Comment: I have also heard it as a story of a Jewish treasurer arrested because his books showed his *true worth* as the amount he had given to tzedaka

Comment: If the citation from a London newspaper is correct, it is probably the London Evening News from Saturday, October 25, 1884 which ran an article on Moses Motefiore's 100th birthday.  https://newspaperarchive.com/tags/moses-montefiore?pr=30&pc=16696&psi=54&pci=6/

Comment: I've checked The Times, and can't find anything there https://www.thetimes.co.uk/archive/find/charity+montefiore/w:1884-10-01~1885-10-31/1?region=global. @YaacovDeane I'm trying www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk (3 free pages!) but it's not sending me an account confirmation email :(

Comment: @Stephen Like many 'print' newspapers, they are now looking for paying customers to allow access to previous editions. When I posted this, it linked to the actual edition. BTW, Shavuah tov and good Mo'ed